# Bind Azure Signal R Services to an existing App service hosting a Signal R server

Tags: azure, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

I need help binding an Azure Signal R service to an existing App service, I haven't found any useful documentation about this, only guides in how to bind them on scratch but never for existing services.
My Azure App service is hosting a Backend Signal R server and I need to add the Azure Signal R services to this existing App service, any sugestions?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna add Azure signalR to your existing App service, you need to

Add a reference to the Microsoft.Azure.SignalR NuGet package by running the following command:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.SignalR
```

Open Program.cs and update the code to the following, it calls the AddSignalR() and AddAzureSignalR() methods to use Azure SignalR Service:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapHub<ChatSampleHub>("/chat");
app.Run();
```

More steps please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet-core#add-azure-signalr-to-the-web-app).

Please note that don't select serverless in ServiceMode dropdown list.

[image]

Please refer to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/concept-service-mode)